# FiPy fork error

Tags: python, mpi, mpi4py, fipy

I am currently trying to use fipy on our local cluster (Scientific Linux 6.9 and Python 2.7.8) to perform some drift-diffusion calculations, and I'm having difficulty with solving in parallel. When I attempt to run my script invoking the --trilinos option I get the following error:

> ---
>
> A process has executed an operation involving a call to the
>   "fork()" system call to create a child process.  Open MPI is currently
>   operating in a condition that could result in memory corruption or
>   other system errors; your job may hang, crash, or produce silent
>   data corruption.  The use of fork() (or system() or other calls that
>   create child processes) is strongly discouraged.
>
> The process that invoked fork was:
>
> Local host:          [[20666,15131],0] (PID 21499)
>
> If you are *absolutely sure* that your application will successfully and
>   and correctly survive a call to fork(), you may disable this warning by setting the mpi_warn_on_fork MCA parameter to 0.
>
> ---

I have isolated this error in the simple script:

```
from mpi4py import *
from fipy import *
```

I think that there is therefore some conflict between mpi4py and fipy but I am lost as to how to diagnose the conflict. Is there something simple I am missing in the installation? I have installed fipy and mpi4py through pip, and PyTrilinos is installed from source.

Comment: Is this a warning or a fatal error ? Which interconnect are you using ? Can you set `export OMPI_MCA_mpi_warn_on_fork=0` and give it an other try ?

Comment: Setting  `export OMPI_MCA_mpi_warn_on_fork=0` seems to have done the trick, so I think it must be a warning rather than a fatal error. I'd still like to know where this is coming from, but solving in parallel is now working at least. Thanks @GillesGouaillardet

Comment: What happens if you place `from mpi4py import *` after `from fipy import *`? FiPy imports mpi4py internally, but does so after importing PyTrilinos. We have found PyTrilinos to be very touchy about import order.

Comment: It seems the fork warning appears at `from fipy import *` regardless of whether mpi4py is imported or not. However I have been using the script for a while now with no noticeable errors, so I think the call to fork is safe enough.